# resignFirstResponder not dismissing ASCII keyboard for UITextField

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a UIViewController with 4 UITextFields, 3 of them use the NumberPad and 1 uses an ASCII keyboard.  I can't get the ASCII keyboard to dismiss when the user touches a background button outside the text field.  The background button works fine to dismiss the NumberPads but doesn't dismiss the ASCII keyboard.

Yes, the ASCII keyboard does have a Done button and that works (I have the delegate set in IB and have implemented textFieldShouldReturn) but I want all the fields to be able to dismiss by touching the background area so they behave consistently (as much as possible).

The background button's action method (below) is called and it does call resignFirstResponder for all my text field objects but the call for the textfield with the ASCII keyboard doesn't dismiss the keyboard, while the other calls for the numeric textfields do dismiss their NumberPads.

```
-(IBAction)backgroundClick:(id)sender
{
    // resignFirstResponder makes the keyboard go away when the 
    // user clicks outside of one of the text fields
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [num1Field resignFirstResponder];  
    [num2Field resignFirstResponder];
    [num3Field resignFirstResponder];
    [num4Field resignFirstResponder];
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I added another line at the beginning of the above function:
    BOOL isIt = [textField isFirstResponder];
While the keyboard was active I touched in the background area and had a breakpoint right after this call , isIt is NO.  I'm not sure why but I guess that's why the resign doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.  The textField's Referencing Outlet was not connected to File's Owner in IB.

I thought I had checked the connections but obviously missed this.